# Android Camera failing on Android 4.2.2(API Level 17)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, webcam

I am trying to use the camera, but it will not start.  the hw.camera.back: Webcam()  the hw.camera.front: webcam()  not sure what else to add since I can't cut and paste the details.

The error I get is Unfortunatley, Camera has stopped.

My Code is as follows, but it is not my code.  When I try to use the camera with out any use of programming I get the same error.

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
```

in the LogCat I have the following.
The one error I see in the LogCat that I don't understand has todo with E-mail which i am not using and I don't even know how to turn that on or off yet.
 D/ExchangeService(617): !!! Email application not found; stopping self

```
03-05 19:39:12.716: I/Choreographer(409): Skipped 90 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-05 19:39:12.736: D/dalvikvm(818): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 20K, 7% free 3675K/3936K, paused 59ms, total 66ms
03-05 19:39:12.875: D/dalvikvm(818): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 7% free 4013K/4276K, paused 61ms, total 64ms
03-05 19:39:13.056: D/Camera(818): app passed NULL surface
03-05 19:39:13.076: V/EmulatedCamera_Camera(40): getCameraInfo
03-05 19:39:13.076: V/EmulatedCamera_BaseCamera(40): getCameraInfo
03-05 19:39:13.203: D/dalvikvm(818): GC_CONCURRENT freed 73K, 5% free 4429K/4656K, paused 12ms+55ms, total 197ms
03-05 19:39:13.203: V/camera(818): Preview size is 640x480
03-05 19:39:13.243: V/EmulatedCamera_Camera(40): setParameters
03-05 19:39:13.263: V/camera(818): startPreview
03-05 19:39:13.263: V/EmulatedCamera_Preview(40): setPreviewWindow: current: 0x0 -> new: 0x0
03-05 19:39:13.263: V/EmulatedCamera_Camera(40): doStartPreview
03-05 19:39:13.263: V/EmulatedCamera_Preview(40): startPreview
03-05 19:39:13.263: D/EmulatedCamera_Camera(40): Starting camera: 640x480 -> NV21(yuv420sp)
03-05 19:39:13.263: V/EmulatedCamera_QemuDevice(40): startDevice
03-05 19:39:13.276: V/EmulatedCamera_Device(40): commonStartDevice: Allocated 0x41c42008 460800 bytes for 307200 pixels in NV21[640x480] frame
03-05 19:39:15.273: D/dalvikvm(818): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 49K, 4% free 4605K/4776K, paused 44ms, total 46ms
03-05 19:39:15.293: I/dalvikvm-heap(818): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.684MB for 1127536-byte allocation
03-05 19:39:15.293: E/EmulatedCamera_QemuClient(40): queryStart: Query failed: Cannot start the camera
03-05 19:39:15.313: E/EmulatedCamera_QemuDevice(40): startDevice: Unable to start device 'AndroidEmulatorVC0' for NV21[640x480] frames
03-05 19:39:15.313: V/EmulatedCamera_Preview(40): stopPreview
03-05 19:39:15.378: D/dalvikvm(818): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 5704K/5880K, paused 85ms, total 85ms
03-05 19:39:15.383: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40): disableMessage: msg_type = 0x10
03-05 19:39:15.383: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_FRAME
03-05 19:39:15.383: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40): **** Currently enabled messages:
03-05 19:39:15.383: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_ERROR
03-05 19:39:15.383: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_FOCUS
03-05 19:39:15.383: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_ZOOM
03-05 19:39:15.383: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_METADATA
03-05 19:39:15.393: V/EmulatedCamera_Camera(40): doStopPreview
03-05 19:39:15.393: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40): disableMessage: msg_type = 0x10
03-05 19:39:15.393: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_FRAME
03-05 19:39:15.393: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40): **** Currently enabled messages:
03-05 19:39:15.393: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_ERROR
03-05 19:39:15.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_FOCUS
03-05 19:39:15.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_ZOOM
03-05 19:39:15.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_METADATA
03-05 19:39:15.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40): disableMessage: msg_type = 0xffff
03-05 19:39:15.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_ERROR
03-05 19:39:15.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_SHUTTER
03-05 19:39:15.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_FOCUS
03-05 19:39:15.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_ZOOM
03-05 19:39:15.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_FRAME
03-05 19:39:15.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_VIDEO_FRAME
03-05 19:39:15.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_POSTVIEW_FRAME
03-05 19:39:15.403: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_RAW_IMAGE
03-05 19:39:15.413: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_COMPRESSED_IMAGE
03-05 19:39:15.413: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_RAW_IMAGE_NOTIFY
03-05 19:39:15.413: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40):     CAMERA_MSG_PREVIEW_METADATA
03-05 19:39:15.413: V/EmulatedCamera_CallbackNotifier(40): **** Currently enabled messages:
03-05 19:39:15.413: V/EmulatedCamera_Camera(40): doStopPreview
03-05 19:39:15.413: V/EmulatedCamera_Camera(40): cancelPicture
03-05 19:39:15.413: V/EmulatedCamera_Camera(40): releaseCamera
03-05 19:39:15.413: V/EmulatedCamera_Camera(40): doStopPreview
03-05 19:39:15.423: V/EmulatedCamera_QemuDevice(40): disconnectDevice
03-05 19:39:15.423: V/EmulatedCamera_QemuDevice(40): disconnectDevice: Disonnected from device 'AndroidEmulatorVC0'
03-05 19:39:15.423: I/CameraClient(40): Destroying camera 0
03-05 19:39:15.423: V/EmulatedCamera_Camera(40): closeCamera
03-05 19:39:15.423: V/EmulatedCamera_Camera(40): doStopPreview
03-05 19:39:15.443: W/dalvikvm(818): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-05 19:39:15.483: E/AndroidRuntime(818): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-67
03-05 19:39:15.483: E/AndroidRuntime(818): java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
03-05 19:39:15.483: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.android.camera.Camera.startPreview(Camera.java:1867)
03-05 19:39:15.483: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.android.camera.Camera.access$3100(Camera.java:87)
03-05 19:39:15.483: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.android.camera.Camera$5.run(Camera.java:1112)
03-05 19:39:15.483: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-05 19:39:15.483: E/AndroidRuntime(818): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
03-05 19:39:15.483: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at android.hardware.Camera.startPreview(Native Method)
03-05 19:39:15.483: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  at com.android.camera.Camera.startPreview(Camera.java:1864)
03-05 19:39:15.483: E/AndroidRuntime(818):  ... 3 more
03-05 19:39:15.513: W/AudioFlinger(40): session id 7 not found for pid 40
03-05 19:39:15.523: W/AudioFlinger(40): session id 8 not found for pid 40
03-05 19:39:15.553: W/ActivityManager(291):   Force finishing activity com.android.camera/.Camera
03-05 19:39:15.772: D/dalvikvm(818): GC_CONCURRENT freed 25K, 3% free 5706K/5880K, paused 67ms+25ms, total 398ms
03-05 19:39:16.013: D/dalvikvm(291): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1373K, 27% free 8210K/11196K, paused 132ms, total 140ms
03-05 19:39:16.363: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
03-05 19:39:16.610: W/ActivityManager(291): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{410f2198 u0 com.android.camera/.Camera}
03-05 19:39:16.813: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
03-05 19:39:16.873: W/EGL_emulation(409): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-05 19:39:29.058: W/ActivityManager(291): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{410f2198 u0 com.android.camera/.Camera}
03-05 19:39:54.407: D/ExchangeService(617): Received deviceId from Email app: null
03-05 19:39:54.407: D/ExchangeService(617): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
03-05 19:39:59.483: D/ExchangeService(617): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
03-05 19:39:59.483: D/ExchangeService(617): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
03-05 19:39:59.543: D/ExchangeService(617): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
03-05 19:39:59.593: W/ActivityManager(291): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
03-05 19:39:59.593: D/ExchangeService(617): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
03-05 19:39:59.643: W/ActivityManager(291): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
03-05 19:39:59.663: E/ActivityThread(617): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d43240 that was originally bound here
03-05 19:39:59.663: E/ActivityThread(617): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d43240 that was originally bound here
03-05 19:39:59.663: E/ActivityThread(617):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
03-05 19:39:59.663: E/ActivityThread(617):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
03-05 19:39:59.663: E/ActivityThread(617):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
```

Comment: Don't worry about the email message, it doesn't have anything to do with your problem. Your problem is that `startPreview()` fails. Can we see some code related to that? Especially interesting is this: `setPreviewWindow: current: 0x0 -> new: 0x0`, since it looks like the preview window isn't being set right.

Comment: it's not my code, its from when i click to start the camera that is provided on the screen.  I was getting the same with my code using Intent, in the prcess of tracking it down I found the camera itself will not work.

Comment: Do you have an actual device(with the same API level) to test it on? If it only crashes on the emulator, I wouldn't worry much.

Comment: I have to get it to work, my instructor feels the 4.2.2 devices work and he docked me 10 points on my last assingment and this is part of the final.  is there a device that everyone knows is working.  I have installed the ADT 3x now

Comment: In that case, let's see some code, just to make sure it's nothing obvious.

Comment: @StephanM : I've never coded for a camera (on real device or emulator) so can't really help but this line from logcat looks like it might be relevant... `ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property` try Googling for that.

Comment: Do either of these questions help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/13413943/752320   http://stackoverflow.com/q/8031803/752320

Comment: No none of these sugestions are working;(

Comment: When It works am I suppose to see actual Video from my Cam and I can capture a picture?

Comment: yes what your intent > startActivity() is doing is simply broadcasting an Intent (or message) to the rest of the phone. The camera on a device uses a broadcast intent receiver to check for this broadcast . when it receives a call to start the camera  (ie `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`) it says "yes" i know how to do that and starts up the phones default image capture activity. And so, to answer your question, Yes it will show a standard Camera activity just as if you clicked the "Camera" application icon.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested this on my physical `Samsung Galaxy Nexus running 4.2.2` and runs perfectly.  (originally i thought I only had 4.2 but i have tested 4.2.2)

I also tested running on emulator which ran perfectly on macbook pro. I was using emulator Target: `"Google APIs (Google Inc) - API Level 17 (4.2.2)"`.

You must make sure you have the following permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

This grants permission to use the camera, autofocus and write to storage

Here is code to start the camera

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent);
```

"111" can be replaced with whatever constant your using to identify the activity in your result call back function.

1) If you already have permissions I suggest you go into `Android Virtual Device Manager` and create a new `AVD` from scratch.

- Device = Galaxy Nexus
- Target = Google APIs (Google Inc) - API Level 17 (4.2.2)
- Hardware Keyboard Present
- Front camera - Webcam
- Back Camera - Webcam

SD Card size = 200 MB. And try with and without, Use Host GPU.

2) Next is to check your webcam. Are you sure the machine your using has a webcam and its functional? Of course if the webcam isn't working or not installed this will break things. Also the drivers on your machine might be problematic with AVD. Otherwise you can try using the "Emulated" option for both, where it basically just shows a test/moving image.

If all this still has problems, then it must be something with the code you have this `intent startActivity` within. You should try starting a new clean project, put the code in there to start activity, modify `AndroidManifest.xml as` I showed and go from there. You could also try running on another machine because possibly the webcam on your machine (if it has one, has conflicting drivers). I tested on a macbook pro and worked 100%

I hope that can help you

Comment: Although very informative I never was able to get the actual webcam0 to start.  But now even though I say to use the webcam0 I get the emulator screen instead. Hopefully this will be enough that I can stuff my own photo into the gallery as if it was taken with the camera.  I will need to find how to do this.  Also I am running on a HP Pavilion dv7 running win7(64)

Comment: @wired00 what is emulated camera option android AVD ?